# FreeBSD 8.3 LATCH. After a few minutes, that connects the Internet

Tags: freebsd, virtualbox

I installed FreeBSD 8.3 DISC1 production in VirtualBox.
I'm trying to install xorg, Or another package:
`pkg_add -r xorg` or `cd usr/ports/x11/xorg && make install clean`

It starts the download, after a few minutes the VM crashes and closes the window of VirtualBox.

Configured in rc.conf: `ifconfig_ec0 = "DHCP"`

Would anyone know why? Is configuration problem? How can I fix this?

Comment: Sounds like a bug in VirtualBox, especially if the VM Window is closing itself...

Comment: Yes, I'm also thinking that might be a bug in VirtualBox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try using a different ethernet controller, like the Intel PRO/1000MT Desktop (em in FreeBSD).

It cannot be a configuration problem. When you say crashes, does the VM itself produce an error, or the OS in it (panic)?

Comment: is still waging. There must log in freebsd error. The window that is running freebsd lock and appears message "Program has stopped working". The virtualbox has some log file? The error happens after a few minutes that I connect to the internet.. have any idea what I can do?

Comment: Maybe a bit far fetched: Are you sure the memory in the host machine is ok? When a program crashes in a strange way when using normally, it might be that the memory is corrupt. I don't know how to check that though.